# how to install ag-grid in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, angularjs, visual-studio-2015, npm, ag-grid

Can someone share steps on adding ag-grid to a Visual Studio 2015 c# project?
I tried "npm install ag-grid", which created node_modules/ag-grid in my project folder, but it didn't add it to the solution. If I add the node_modules folder to the solution, and try to rebuild, I get errors:

> "Build: Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is
>   provided.
>   C:\SVN\SolutionName\ProjectName\node_modules\ag-grid\dist\lib\entities\rowNode.d.ts   5"

and

> "Build: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is
>   subject to change in a future release. Specify
>   '--experimentalDecorators' to remove this warning.
>   C:\SVN\SolutionName\ProjectName\node_modules\ag-grid\src\ts\cellNavigationService.ts"

[image]

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

[Get Started with ag-Grid in Your Project](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/#get-started-with-ag-grid-in-your-project) - link will help you getting started with [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid). Seems like you are using .Net MVC, so you need to use JavaScript version of it.

Reference js and CSS files from index.html: [Doc Reference](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/#add-ag-grid-to-your-project), no need to `npm install`

```
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.min.noStyle.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css">
</head>
```